# Converted IFC data format (from nwd) in ArcGIS Pro is not visible

Tags: arcgis-pro, convert, ifc

I have received a nwd 3D Model from a client which needs to be visualized in ArcGIS. I informed myself that this data needs to be converted in any CAD formats (DWG, IFC) to be able to be seen in ArcGIS. The data is visible in AutoDesk but after converting the data to IFC and importing in ArcGIS Pro (3.1.0), nothing is shown. What could be the reason?

Comment: Since the data isn't available to us, your Question ought to describe the exact conversion process used, the row count(s) after conversion, and the coordinate references of the canvas and dataset(s).. At that point we might be able to guess at what has gone wrong.